# Can I store all database into google drive?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-storage, cloud

Is it possible to store, view videos and download videos in app from Google drive?

Can I use google drive as cloud database?

Firebase only has 1 GB free storage but Google drive has 15GB free.

I need to develop an app for school to access a video for education in the  future for a higher skill level.

Answer (score 0):

The correct application and way for this type of application, to store your data, such as videos, images, any bigger files in general, is [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage). As the official documentation says:

> Cloud Storage is designed to help you quickly and easily store and serve user-generated content, such as photos and videos.

You can access this open [Github repository](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android) for a full example in Android of using Cloud Storage. Besides that, the steps to start using Cloud Storage are pretty simple, as you can check below.

1. Add the dependency for the Cloud Storage for Firebase Android library to your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually app/build.gradle):

   ```
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1
   ```
2. The first step in accessing your storage bucket is to create an instance of FirebaseStorage:

   ```
   FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
   ```

WIth this, Cloud Storage is added to your project. I would recommend you to get a full tutorial with steps and explanation in the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start).

Let me know if the information helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help to provide me all information about Google cloud.

Google will cost me for store videos at more than 5GB,

Firebase Spark has Cloud storage limits are up to 5GB of store data and downloads of up to 1GB/day, Google Drive has 15GB of storage for free that is advantage to act as database.

There are better Cloud storage and Cloud database has more size than firebase?